# Best practice with VueJS (or every frontend framework) and Firebase CLI

Tags: firebase, vue.js

I have a newbie question concerning the architecture of my app and what practice is better.

I have a Vue project, lets call it frontendProject (it does not really matter as my problem would have been the same with another framework) with all my file for the frontend of my website.

I recently discover all hidden feature of firebase (like function, deploy etc).

My question is simple, should i use Firebase CLI to install all functionnality like deploy, back end function etc IN the folder frontendProject OR should i create a new project dedicated for firebase and the backend, lets call it backendProject.

What is making me hesitate is the fact that i can deploy wathever is in a folder (which i pointed on dist from vue) in the firebase project, and i don't know if there will be new feature by the futur that need the firebase project to be mix with the frontend. But i'm not sure if this can mess up the project. The front end build only take the "src" folder to build if i'm right ? Which mean i'm not building useless file from firebas project when i build with vue.

If i'm not clear on any point don't hesitate to tell me.

Thanks in advance from the community

Comment: Personally, I tend to have a single project directory with my `firebase.json` at the top level, and a `web` subdirectory that contains my e.g. Vue project. Then I set the "public" dir to e.g. `web/build` or whatever the build output is, and separately have Cloud Functions in a `functions` directory that is a sibling of `web`.

Comment: Thanks, i think i'll have the same project structure as it looks more attractive that mixing everything together, and still keep this useful deploy function !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from @MichaelBleigh

In root of the project set up firebase,and then put VueJs project in a `web` folder, then in the firebase.json, point the dist folder of vuejs so that you can deploy easily your project on firebase host